# How to migrate jsonb data model to Diesel 2.x?

Tags: postgresql, rust, jsonb, rust-diesel

In Diesel 1.x, I defined a model that reflects a `jsonb` data type like this:

```
use diesel::pg::types::sql_types::Jsonb;

#[derive(FromSqlRow, AsExpression, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
#[sql_type = "Jsonb"]
pub struct ChannelTag {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
}
```

When I upgraded Diesel to 2.0.4 today and compile the project, I get an error:

```
error[E0603]: module `types` is private
 --> src/model/app/cruise/channel/channel_tag.rs:1:17
  |
1 | use diesel::pg::types::sql_types::Jsonb;
  |                 ^^^^^ private module
```

It seems they turned the `types` module to private and no longer expose it externally? So what should I do to define the `jsonb` data type in Diesel 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply moved modules. You can find it in [`diesel::pg::sql_types`](https://docs.rs/diesel/2.1.1/diesel/pg/sql_types/index.html) or even just [`diesel::sql_types`](https://docs.rs/diesel/2.1.1/diesel/sql_types/index.html) when using a Postgres database. So your code should look like this after migrating:

```
use diesel::pg::sql_types::Jsonb;

#[derive(FromSqlRow, AsExpression, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
#[diesel(sql_type = Jsonb)]
pub struct ChannelTag {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
}
```

Pro tip: you can answer these kind of import issues yourself by first giving the documentation [a quick search](https://docs.rs/diesel/2.1.1/diesel/index.html?search=json) when you have import issues. Module re-organization is a natural part of updating major versions of a library.